# How to check application password in wordpress rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using application password for my wordpress application. I need a way to check it when it's passed into the header, is there ay function I can use in my permissions callback?

At the moment I hve this code in my custom plugin

```php
register_rest_route(
 $this->namespace,
 '/my-route',
 array(
   'methods' => 'GET',
   'callback' => array($this, 'get_users_list'),
   'permissions_callback' => function( WP_REST_Request $request ){
     // need to check the application password here
   }
 )
);
```

Thank you for the help